# Changing first boolen that is false to true in postgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table where all values of the column `requested` are `false`. I perform an action in python and want to update the first row where `requested` is `false` to `true`. So, after the first execution in python, the first row is set to `true`. After the second execution - since `requested` in the first row is now `true` - the second row is set to `true` and so on. My sql statement looks like this:

```
UPDATE timeframes SET requested = TRUE 
WHERE requested = (
    SELECT requested FROM timeframes 
    WHERE requested = FALSE 
    ORDER BY id 
    LIMIT 1);
```

This statement sets ALL the values in requested to true. I don't know why. If I execute the subquery as its own query, it only returns the first row. So in my opinion the update statement should therefore only set that specific row to true. Any idea as to why my statement doesn't work and how to improve it?

EDIT: Changing WHERE requested IN to WHERE id IN worked. The statement should look like this:

```
UPDATE timeframes SET requested = TRUE 
WHERE id = (
    SELECT id FROM timeframes 
    WHERE requested = FALSE 
    ORDER BY id 
    LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: should it not be WHERE id IN ( select id ... ) ?

Comment: Since your subquery is returning a single value, there is no benefit in using `IN`; rather, `WHERE id = (...)` makes more sense.

Comment: I didn't know that, but that makes sense. I changed it accordingly, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your update executes ...

```
where requestet = false
```

to update only the first row with a unique id change your update statement to

```
UPDATE timeframes SET requested = TRUE 
WHERE id = (
    SELECT id FROM timeframes 
    WHERE requested = FALSE 
    ORDER BY id 
    LIMIT 1);
```

as written in the comments, by amadan, you can either use `where id in`, or better in this situation `where id =`